# I want to know scroll bar is at end in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am coding a while loop in selenium, and want to condition my while loop, so when the scroll bar is at its end of its scroll the while loop should stop. How can i code this type of condition in while loop? Iam using Keys.DOWN and my while loop is right now set to True

My code of while loop:

```
    while True:
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('pane-side').send_keys(Keys.DOWN * 5)
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll in a while loop you could check the pages Y offset is changed after you use `send_keys(Keys.DOWN * 5)`

```py
from time import sleep

# Offset can not be smaller then 0
# we just want to ensure that we will try to scroll down at least once
previous_offset = -1

# current_offset (most probably 0)
current_offset = self.driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset;')

while previous_offset!=current_offset:
    previous_offset = current_offset
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('pane-side').send_keys(Keys.DOWN * 5)

    # Give a browser some small time to react
    sleep(0.1)
    current_offset = driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset;')
```

If you don't need to use the loop and want to scroll down to the end of the page you can just do

```py
self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
```