# How to stop the automatic scroll-down when user scroll up?

Tags: python, scroll, automation

I want to stop the automatic scroll down  when user scroll up by mouse. I have made a function that scroll's down the webpage automatically after every 2 second but I want to stop that automatic scroll when user scroll up by mouse
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("https://YouTube.com") 
driver. maximize_window() 
a=input('press y if you want to scroll down') 
if a=='y':
    while(True) :                  
          driver. execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 150) ", "")
          time.sleep(2) 
else:
Print(" Ok")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways in which you can solve this is using the `window.pageYOffset` property.

From the Docs

> The read-only Window property pageYOffset is an alias for scrollY; as such, it returns the number of pixels the document is currently scrolled along the vertical axis (that is, up or down) with a value of 0.0, indicating that the top edge of the Document is currently aligned with the top edge of the window's content area.

So what you will have to do is each time you scroll in the loop keep a count of the increase in `y` and for the condition of your loop, you should check that the `pageYOffset == YScrolled`. If it equals there's no user input, otherwise there is.

There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926201/i-want-to-know-scroll-bar-is-at-end-in-selenium-python)